# Re-creating Google homepage

Tags: html, css

Hello Stack Overflow community! I am a complete beginner to programming and am attempting to learn my way around HTML and CSS at the moment. One of the projects I am working on is to re-create the Google homepage without looking at the source code. I am struggling right now with positioning of various elements (logo, search box, footer).

Can someone look at my code and tell me specifically why my positioning will not work on the three elements I mentioned?

Also, is my HTML semantically correct when it comes to "id" and "class"? Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>

<title>Google</title>

<div class="container">

<nav id="nav">
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="#">+You</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Maps</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Play</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gmail</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drive</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>

<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" alt="Google" width=280     height=95/>


<div id="sign">SIGN IN</div>

<form>
<input type="text"> 
</form>

<div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Advertising Programs</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Business Solutions</a><li>
                <li><a href="#">Privacy & Terms</a><li>
                    <li><a href="#">+Google</a><li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Google</a><li>
    </ul>
</div>



.container {
width: auto;
height: 600px;
position: relative;
}

#nav {
background-color: #333333;
height:30px;

}

li a {
text-decoration: none;
font-family: arial;
color: #ABABAB;
float: left;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 600;
margin-top: 2px;
margin-right: 13px;

}

img {
margin-left: 130px;
margin-top: 195px;
}

#sign {
border: 2px solid #D94A4A;
background-color: #D94A4A;
height: 16px;
width: 65px;
float: right;
margin-right: 40px;
margin-top: 20px;
border-radius: 3px;
font-size: 11px;
font-family: arial;
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-weight: 600;
padding-top: 7px;

}

input {
width: 550px;
height: 25px;
border: 1px solid #3492F7;
margin-top: 290px;
margin-left: 670px;
}

#footer {
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
font-family: verdana;
display: inline;

}
```

Comment: Looking at source code is one of the best ways to learn... and it'd be a bit difficult to help you with what's fundamentally a CSS problem without your CSS in `main.css`.

Comment: To check if your code is semantically correct you should use http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @Santz The W3 validator won't tell you if you're using id/class in a semantically appropriate manner.

Comment: Yes it will. For instance, if you repeat the use of an ID, it will tell you that IDs are unic identifiers, and that you shouldn't use them more than once.

Comment: @Santz So I guess if I use id="id1" that's totally semantic because it passes validation?

Comment: @Santz Validation!=Semantics. Multiple use of an id would make it invalid. Using a class name of 'bluetable' and styling it red would be an issue of semantics.

Comment: @Preet You are not closing your `<li>` tags in the footer list. You're just opening new `<li>` tags.

Comment: @MatthewGreen, using a classname of `bluetable` is an issue of semantics.  `table-primary` or `financial-table` would be semantically correct (Reason: say your employer decides they want everything to be purple one day, and blood-red the next.  Classes describe function, not appearance).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Right. We are both saying the same thing. Though your example is much more clear.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand That's what I ment. However, it seems I didn't understand Preet's question about semantics. I'm sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot some basics : see **Uzziel's answer for precisions**, he pointed those accurately (comments too).

However, you should know that **Stack Overflow is not a place to get all your code corrected for you, but** I think it could be helpful for you to see where it was wrong.

I tried not to change the HTML structure too much, I did a few modifications mainly in the CSS.

There's a website, JSFiddle.net, where you can edit HTML and CSS (and JS) online and see the result ± instantly.

[I put my code here, so you can tweak it as you wish afterwhile.](http://jsfiddle.net/hpC88/)

---

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              +You
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              Search
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              Images
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              Maps
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              Play
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              YouTube
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              News
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              Gmail
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              Drive
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              Calendar
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              More
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div id="sign">
        SIGN IN
      </div>
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" alt="Google" />
      <form>
        <input type="text" />
      </form>
      <div id="footer">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              Advertising Programs
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              Business Solutions
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              Privacy & Terms
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              +Google
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              About Google
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

---

### CSS :

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    position: relative;
}

nav {
    background - color: #333333;
    height: 30px;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
    color: # ABABAB;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    font - size: 13px;
    font - weight: 600;
    margin - top: 2px;
    margin - right: 13px;
}

img {
    width: 280px;
    margin: 195px auto 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#
sign {
    border: 2px solid# D94A4A;
    background - color: #D94A4A;
    height: 16px;
    width: 65px;
    float: right;
    margin - right: 40px;
    margin - top: 20px;
    border - radius: 3px;
    font - size: 11px;
    font - family: arial;
    text - align: center;
    color: white;
    font - weight: 600;
    padding - top: 7px;
}

input {
    width: 550px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #3492F7;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
}

# footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    font - family: verdana;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help. I am trying to absorb as much as I can from various sources. I look forward to learning from all of you!

Comment: For future reference, [CodeReview.se] is good for questions like this.  Read their [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and post there if your question applies.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some basic HTML structure - you don't close the HEAD tag; there is no BODY tag; you don't close the HTML tag.

No, the code you presented is not semantically correct when it comes to ID and CLASS because you're not closing all of your DIVs.  The "container" DIV in particular isn't closed.  Just remember when using ID and CLASS that an ID should only show up once in the document; CLASS can be re-used as often as you want.